# rerun javascript on callback

Tags: javascript

I have a page which shows a map (PolyMap - polymaps.org) within a Devexpress CallbackPanel. When the page initially loads, the map loads just fine, but when a callback is performed within the CallbackPanel, the map does not load. I think that I have narrowed it down to the fact that the javascript is not being reinitialized on the callback, and I know that I need to handle this through the CallbackPanel-EndCallback event.

What I don't know, is how to actually accomplish this in my JS function. I am REALLY new to javascript, and I know how to call specific functions from another function, but I run a complex series of functions within a separate javascript file to load the map using the following tag at the bottom of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/PolyMaps/DiseaseMap.js" id="MapLoad"></script>
```

I would really like to avoid having to completely re-write everything into the EndCallback function, and I know that this has to be a really simple answer, but how do I reinitialize the entire script within another javascript function? i.e.

```
Function ReRun() {
    //Re-Initialize MapLoad Script
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encapsulate all of the initialization logic in a single function, defined in `DiseaseMap.js`:

```
function initMap() {
    // lots of work here
}

initMap();
```

Then just call that function again:

```
function ReRun() {
    initMap();
}
```